# Reading an operator and a number with decimal point as char then using it? (in C)

Tags: c

Here's my problem:
I have to read one of the 2 kinds of phrases
either +x
or *x
and then i have to use that operation i just read.
like, let's say i have some average number i calculated, then i read +3
so the average will now be what it was+3
same with the *function
I managed to do the plus part, and here's my really ugly (but working) code for it:

```
char c=0;
char tempchar=0;
char sign=0;
printf("enter a character\n");
while (c!= '\n' && c!=EOF)
{
    tempchar=c;
    c = getchar();
    if (c=='+' || c=='*')
        sign = c;
    if (c=='\n' || c==EOF)
    {
        c=tempchar;
        break;
    }
}
if (sign == '+')
    avg = avg + (c-'0');
```

so, the + one works.
but for the * option, i only get the last character i entered (e.g. if i enter *1.2 i'll get * and 2) so... how can i make it so i'll get the * and the whole number?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for the future, please refrain from unnecessary profanity in your posts. I've already edited it out.

Comment: How is `avg` defined? Is `avg = avg + (c-'0');` an ASCII-to-integer conversion? if so,isn't `avg = avg * 10 + (c-'0')`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that line... avg is defined as int and the avg = avg + (c-'0') is to get the value of c in numbers rather then it's ASCII code (not sure if that answers your question but i didn't completely get it)

P.S. Linuxios, sorry, I will. I completely forgot about that part in the printf

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to support floating point numbers, make `avg` a `float`, get the input string with `fgets`, and parse it with `sscanf`:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#define MAXBUFFER 64

//... 

float value;
char input[MAXBUFFER];

fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

if (sscanf(input, "+ %f", &value) == 1) avg += value;
if (sscanf(input, "* %f", &value) == 1) avg *= value;

//...
```

Comment: The space before the `%` is redundant as `%f` already skips whitespace.  Might want a space before the `+` and `*` to skip (ignore) leading whitespace.